# How to find trigger that stopping a table to be dropped

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Whenever I run the below command to drop the table,

`DROP TABLE MYTable`

I get this error message,

```
You do not have the privilege
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

According to our DBA I have all permissions. I think some trigger stopping the statement to execute. So how to find this trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more likely to be a Database Trigger. Using SSMS expand the database in the object Explorer, then Programmability and the Database Triggers. You *should* find the trigger there (if there's several,. it's up to you to find the right one though).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a DDL Trigger so you can find it in:

```
Server Objects (Node) > Triggers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also find Database DDL Trigger using below given Query
 SELECT name,parent_class_desc 
 FROM sys.triggers

name                parent_class_desc
-----------------   ----------------
trg_index_changes   DATABASE (Datbase Level Trigger - DDL)
testTriiger         OBJECT_OR_COLUMN  (Table Trigger)